# Did Reen know that Vin was an Allomancer?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

It would seem that others in her crew figured it out:

> Vin frowned. “Camon was an Allomancer?”
>
> Kelsier shook his head. “He must have admitted to something heinous during his torture.” Kelsier glanced at Vin. “**He must have known what you were, Vin.** He used you intentionally.”
>
> She paled slightly. “Then . . . the Ministry knows that I’m a Mistborn?”
>
> “Perhaps. It depends on whether Camon knew or not. **He could have assumed you were just a Misting.**”
>   <sub>The Final Empire - Chapter 11</sub>

And Reen knew who her father was:

> Vin clinched her teeth, then forced herself to relax. “I saw my father at the ball tonight,” she said, hoping to distract Kelsier and the others away from Lord Venture.
>
> “Really?” Kelsier asked with interest.
>
> Vin nodded. **“I recognized him from a time [Reen] pointed him out to me."**
>
> “What is this?” Renoux asked.
>
> “Vin’s father is an obligator,” Kelsier said.
>   <sub>The Final Empire - Chapter 13</sub>

And  he worked very hard to keep her from the attention of the Inquisitors:

> Reen was not a good person. He beat Vin, he was selfish, and he was conniving. However, he did love his sister. Most of his beatings happened because he was worried that she would expose them somehow and get herself killed. **He knew that the Inquisitors were chasing her because of her half-breed nature, and so he uprooted them constantly**, moving from city to city. He kept her alive, teaching her to be harsh, but teaching her to survive.
>   <sub>[Annotation - Mistborn Chapter 37 Part One](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-mistborn-chapter-thirty-seven-part-one/)</sub>

<sup>(all emphasis mine)</sup>

So did Reen ever know or suspect Vin was anything other then a simple half-breed? If so, did he know she was a full mistborn?

Comment: If you make it to the third book, *The Hero of Ages*, the nature of what Reen knew about Vin becomes a critical and complex element of the story. Because Sanderson substantively transforms the reader's understanding of who Vin (and others) are through various reveals, I think it is difficult to provide an answer to this question that does not pull a ***humongous*** spoiler over the entire series. (And I write that as someone who generally dislikes using spoiler-tags. :)

Comment: I have read all the mistborn books, but I disagree that it is made clear given that it was Ruin, not Reen, in *THA*. If you could, please go ahead and answer, you can just note at the top that it will spoil the whole series.

Comment: Is it just me, or did Ruin's reveal indicate that Reen *was entirely* Ruin operating through the hemalurgic connection? That is, wasn't Reen entirely a construct of Ruin?

Comment: @Lexible Only the "voice" version of Reen was Ruin.  Ruin did not take physical form and pretend to be Vin's brother.  There is no indication that Reen was being used by Ruin in any way.

Comment: @Tim Are we sure Reen—including Vin's perception of him—was not entirely a creation of Ruin (like an imaginary friend)? I do not recall Reen interacting with any other character but Vin.

Comment: @Lexible Reen was definitely a real person, right up until he was killed by a Steel Inquisitor.  Reen's death was revealed to Vin by an Inquisitor, which demonstrates that Reen interacted with other people.  Also, who looked after Vin all those years from when she was a toddler, if not Reen?

Comment: @Lexible Additionally, only some of the "Reen" voices were Ruin.

Comment: @Tim "Who looked after?" Um: *Ruin* who seemingly had an interest in her dating back to when her mother was alive?

Comment: @Lexible Ruin is incapable of taking physical form.

Comment: @Tim Right. Hence "like an imaginary friend." :) I can see that the answer may be "It's just you." when I asked "Is it just me..." :)

Comment: @Lexible It's definitely just you :-)